# HTML5 and CSS 3 - Div text Vertical Align Middle

Tags: html, css

Please help,

i want to align the header menu/nav links to vertically align. See:

http://hyindia.com/demo/myoffshore/index.html

See the CODE here:

```
nav ul { list-style-type:none; padding:0px; margin:0px; float:left; width:100%;}
nav ul li { float:left; width:119px; height:66px;}
nav ul li a { 
 float:left;
 width:119px;
 height:66px;
 font:bold 15px 'Myriad Pro';
 color:#fff;
 text-shadow:1px 1px #1f1f1f;
 text-align:center;
}

<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="nav1">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="nav2">HEALTH INSURANCE</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="nav3">LIFE INSURANCE</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="nav4">OVERSEAS MORTGAGES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="nav5">ESTATE PLANNING</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="nav6">BANKING</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="nav7">WEALTH MANAGEMENT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="nav8">QROPS</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is quite vague, which one are you talking about? One is already aligned... :/

Comment: @Sonu , Tom is correct there is one which is already aligned vertically.

Comment: Sorry guys, I forgot to add the word middle. I want the top menu/nav (colorful) links to be align vertically middle!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since some of your nav items have text spanning several rows you won't be able to use the classic line-height-trick (which would be to set the line-height equal to the height).

Instead I'd suggest changing your menu styling to use `display: table/table-row/table-cell` since tables are excellent at vertically aligning things in the middle.

What you need to do is to change your entire `nav` styling to this:

```
nav {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

    nav ul {
        display: table-row;
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

        nav ul li {
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

            nav ul li a {
                display: block;
                padding: 5px 10px;
            }
```

Remove all the floats and widths + heights (using padding on the `a` instead) etc (what I have above is all you should have).

You'll also need to move the actual background styling from the `a`s to the `li`s since the `a`s won't be equal in height any more (but the `li`s will).

Comment: Thanks you so much for your code and little tutorial about css "powerbuoy" .

Comment: This is not HTML5 or CSS3.

Comment: So? :P Besides, the `nav` element _is_ HTML5 (http://html5doctor.com/nav-element/). `display: table` is old but newlishly supported though.

Answer (score -1):

Here is five methods very well explained : http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/